# io.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, arduino

I have this code working for receiving data from my Arduino but I will like to send data back  to my Arduino and get a response on my client page. I added a listening function but I keep getting `io.on is not a function` when I send data from my client page.

**test.js**

```
io.listen(app.listen(3000)).on('connection', function (client) {

    // store client into array
    clients.push(client);

    // on disconnect
    client.on('disconnect', function() {

        // remove client from array
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(client), 1);


    });

    // I added this to listen for event from my chart.JS

    io.on('connection', function(socket){

        socket.on('LED on', function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        });
        socket.on('LED off', function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Not your current problem but you're going to want to take the parentheses off the end of `ledOn();` and `ledOff();` on lines like `document.getElementById('ON').onclick = ledOn();`. That's going to call those functions immediately and assign their return value (`undefined`) to `onclick`. It should be `document.getElementById('ON').onclick = ledOn;`

Comment: What libraries are you using? What platform are you on? What is the full stack trace / error message?

Comment: that's an http server app? usually you do it like `var app = require('http').createServer(handler)`
`var io = require('socket.io')(app);` `app.listen(PORT)` `io.on('connection', function (socket) { //...`

Comment: @robertotomás I got my socket.io already working listening for event on this function. I'm just looking to send data back. Do you **really** need to include all of these ?

Comment: For setting up socket io with express.js, see this https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your value of `io` is not what it should be.

The usual way of doing things is like this:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

io.on('connect', ...);
```

But I'm guessing that your value of `io` is something like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
```

That's not the same thing.  That's the module handle.  But, when you do it this way:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
```

Then, `io` is a socket.io instance.  You can bind listeners to an instance, not to the module handle.

---

In every single socket.io server-side example on [this doc page](http://socket.io/docs/), they use one of these forms:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(port);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

with this:

```
 io.on('connection', ....);
```

Nowhere do they do:

```
var io = require('socket.io`);
io.listen(server);
io.on('connection', ....);
```

That's just the wrong value for `io`.

---

Long story, shortened, you need to fix what you assign to `io` to be consistent with the docs.  It's the return value from `require('socket.io')(app);` that gives you a socket.io instance object that you can then set up event handlers on.

Comment: Thanks responding. You're entirely right. However, I got a structure that already works. It connects to my Arduino via ethernet and stores my sensor data in my MongoDB using Socket.IO. Do you think adding the above mentioned would mess things up ? I can provide a JSfiddle link so you see what I got and how I'm trying to achieve this.

Comment: @Ekom - Doing things the correct way will not mess things up so I don't really know how else to respond.

Comment: @Ekom - If the particular error you wrote about is solved now, you should wrap up this question as we don't want to continue to add follow-on issues to the original question.  If you are still stuck, you can post more of your relevant code in a new question, describe all the relevant debugging you've done and clues you've discovered and then ask in a new question for help with the next issue.

Comment: Okay! I have posted another question. Thanks for your [input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627659/socketio-data-undefined)

Comment: Please kindly help me take a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640416/socketio-server-not-sending-data-to-arduino?noredirect=1#comment70481638_41640416)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server   = require('http').Server(app);
var io       = require('socket.io')(server);

let APP_PORT=3000;

server.listen(APP_PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`SERVER RUNNING ON PORT : ${APP_PORT}`);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

       /* SOCKET - CORE EVENTS  */

       socket.on('connect', (message) => {
          console.log("connected: " + message+"socket_id:"+socket.id);
       });

       socket.on('disconnect',(data)=>{
          console.log('user disconnected:' + socket.id);
       });

       socket.on('error', function (err){
          console.log('received error from client:', socket.id,' Error :',err);
       });
});
```