# socketIO data undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to send data from my client to my server side. I only get `undefined`. I would like the user to click the ledOn function  to send `1` and also click the ledOff  to send `0` to the server.

**server.js**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('ON', function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    });
    socket.on('OFF', function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    });
});
```

**client.js**

```
function ledOn() {
 socket.emit ('ON');
     document.getElementById("ON").value = "1"
 console.log("Led is ON ");
 }

 function ledOff() {
 socket.emit('OFF');
     document.getElementById("OFF").value = "0"
 console.log("Led is Off");

 }
```

**index.HTML**

```
<div id="ON">
<input type="submit" value="Led ON" onclick="ledOn()">
</div>
<div id="OFF">
<input type="submit" value="Led OFF" onclick="ledOff()">
</div>
```

Comment: You're not sending any data while calling listener. It should be like `socket.emit('OFF', 'yourData');` First parameter is your listener name and rest are the parameters.

Comment: Thanks I totally skipped out on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `client.js` to emit some data in the case of an `"ON"` or `"OFF"` event. For example, below, I am sending a `"1"` and `"0"` in `ledOn()` and `ledOff()` respectively.

```
function ledOn() {
    socket.emit ('ON', "1");
    document.getElementById("ON").value = "1"
    console.log("LED is on");
 }

 function ledOff() {
    socket.emit('OFF', "0");
    document.getElementById("OFF").value = "0"
    console.log("LED is off");
 }
```

Check out the Socket.IO [docs](http://socket.io/docs/) to see some of their examples.