# socket.io TypeError: socket.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am developing a node app using express which has a chatting system and I am using socket.io but I get this error

```
Server is listening on 3000
made socket connection
C:\Users\User\MyFolder\Projects\FMIS\app\app.js:139
socket.on('chat', function(data){
       ^

TypeError: socket.on is not a function
at Namespace.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\User\MyFolder\Projects\FMIS\app\app.js:139:12)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Namespace.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Namespace.emit 
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

This what I have tried to do in my `app.js

```
var reload = require('reload');
var bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var  socket = require('socket.io');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views','app/views');
app.locals.siteTitle = "FMIS";
app.use(express.static('app/public'));

app.use(require('./routes/Chat_api'));
app.use(require('./routes/Chat'));

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
console.log('Server is listening on '+ app.get('port'));
});

var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection',function(){
    console.log('made socket connection');
    socket.on('chat', function(data){
        // io.sockets.emit('chat',data);
        console.log(data);
    });
});
reload(server, app);
```

I send and recieve data from the client like this

```
 socket.emit('chat',{
          user: chatUsername.value,
          Message: chatMessage.value
        });

socket.on('chat',function(data){
        // showMessage(data);
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623528/io-on-is-not-a-function This might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the library reference for socket.io, which does not contain the function property `on`. What are you trying to do is use the socket provided to you as an argument of the callback on `io.on` connection event. To fix that you can just add `socket` to the arguments on your callback function. Like this:

```
io.on('connection',function(socket) {
  console.log('made socket connection');
  socket.on('chat', function(data){
    // io.sockets.emit('chat',data);
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Now `socket` is referring to the socket provided to you by the connection. See [this example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was that i'm using socket.current in my main app so ,  it didnt recognized socket.on but socket.current.on instead