# socketio io.on is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, chat

I have seen many solutions on the web but they didn't help me much.

I have created a working `nodejs` authentication system in `express.js` framework. i just want to add a `chat` function that help us to get the information about it .

the route is

```
const dashboard = require('./routes/dashboard').dash;
```

and the calling function is

```
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard)
```

on this code page `./rotes/dashboard.js` i'm exporting them like this

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var app = express();
const io = require('socket.io');
const fs = require('fs');

const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../db/auth.js');


//exporting dashboard 
module.exports = {
  dash: router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    var chat = io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
      console.log('chat is connected');
    })
    res.render('dashboard', {chat:chat});

  })
}
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
io.on is not a function
TypeError: io.on is not a function
    at E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\routes\dashboard.js:13:19
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at E:\expressBasedLOginSignUP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
```

someone help me how to avoid this function and why this is happening.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623528/io-on-is-not-a-function

Comment: no its not because i'm using it on express embeded framework an it  didn't work although it works when i'm not using the express embeded framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.io` returns a function, you have to call the function and pass your http server reference to it.

Example:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

And then you can call events on it.